# Accamulated data in pivot mode

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Now i accamulate columns via row_cumsum

```
test
| project Boenheter, Ar, Maned, ManedTLA 
| extend _date = make_datetime(toint(Ar), Maned, 1) 
| extend key1 = Ar, __auto0 = datetime_part('Month', startofmonth(_date)) 
| summarize value0 = sum(Boenheter) by key1, __auto0, ManedTLA 
| order by __auto0 asc, key1 asc 
| serialize value0 = **row_cumsum(value0, __auto0 != prev(__auto0))** 
| extend __p = pack(tostring(ManedTLA), value0) 
| summarize __p = make_bag(__p) by key1 
| evaluate bag_unpack(__p) 
| order by key1 asc
```

[image]

But i wanna do accamulation for rows in next approach:
Feb = Jan + Feb, Mar = Jan + Feb + Mar, etc... so Feb = 304, Mar = 624 (for 2012 year as example) and so on

[image]

Does Kusto have some hack for do accamulation for row instead columns (row_cumsum)?

Help please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_cumsum`, with restart on year change, before using `pivot`

```
// Generation of a data sample. No part of the solution.
let t = materialize(range i from 1 to 200 step 1 | extend dt = ago(365d*10*rand()));
// The solution starts here.
t
| summarize count() by year = getyear(dt), month = format_datetime(dt,'MM')
| order by year asc, month asc
| extend cumsum = row_cumsum(count_, year != prev(year))
| evaluate pivot(month, any(cumsum), year)
```

| year | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 |  |  |  |  | 2 | 4 |  | 6 | 7 | 10 | 14 | 16 |
| 2013 | 2 | 3 | 7 | 8 | 10 | 11 | 15 | 16 |  | 17 |  | 18 |
| 2014 | 2 | 7 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |  | 17 |  | 19 | 20 |
| 2015 | 2 | 3 | 6 |  |  | 10 | 11 | 12 |  | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 2016 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 8 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 15 | 16 | 19 |
| 2017 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 8 | 13 | 16 |  | 17 | 20 |  |  | 21 |
| 2018 | 4 | 5 | 8 | 12 |  | 15 | 18 | 20 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 |
| 2019 | 5 | 7 | 8 |  | 10 | 11 | 14 | 18 |  | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 2020 | 2 | 5 | 8 | 10 | 11 |  | 13 | 15 | 16 | 19 | 22 |  |
| 2021 | 2 |  | 5 | 6 |  |  | 7 | 8 | 9 | 11 |  | 17 |
| 2022 |  | 2 | 4 | 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA02PwU7DMAyG75P2Dj%20nJVO1biC4oJ05jRP3ySzeWqlJKtcdDO3hcVZA3Ow43//ZdY0XTiykbU7IRxACKWGg2He8wmtGT6Jlog1jyN1Yfq7ms44Vii0iKUtLXfvFTiidGC2OkiM20Iz79RqDcm/dFfypnAJCweiU3cPTY1hu1kvDgvPeP89ndY23fx5jzT6gYWFz6nx2xTDGSGI6HPKY1Hm8X3BhEks9sZbKBfUVYk7a2OMxiy25t7tY28g2rBa73cKXsCyB5S%20AhsMvZmWZ/6x8GKNpLUvyx35q3M2%20rybybote%20OxK42/JfKZuNCX69pzV3VIrULq4ifcT6b8Bs8QpZoIBAAA=)

Comment: Cool solution, perfect for me, Thanks)